# Postnikov square explicitly on a simplicial complex

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homological-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$

Following [Wikipedia, a Postnikov square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postnikov_square) is a certain cohomology operation from a first cohomology group $H^1$ to a third cohomology group $H^3$, introduced by Postnikov (1949). Eilenberg (1952) described a generalization taking classes in $H^t$ to $H^{2t+1}$ which requires that $t$ is odd.

Here I consider the specific Postnikov square $\mathfrak{P}_3$ (hopefully) defined by $$\mathfrak{P}_3: H^2(-,\Z_{3^k})\to H^5(-,\Z_{3^{k+1}})$$ given by
$$
\mathfrak{P}_3(u)=\beta_{(3^{k+1},3^k)}(u\cup u)
$$
where $\beta_{(3^{k+1},3^k)}$ is the Bockstein homomorphism associated with $0\to\Z_{3^{k+1}}\to\Z_{3^{2k+1}}\to\Z_{3^k}\to0$ and  $u \in H^2(M,\Z_{3^k})$.

Let us focus on $k=1$ case,
$$\mathfrak{P}_3(u)=\beta_{(3^{2},3)}(u\cup u)=\beta_{(9,3)}(u\cup u).$$
Here $u \in H^2(M,\Z_3)$ that we can define as a 2nd cohomology class (also 2-cocycle) with a $\Z_3$ coefficient on a manifold $M$. For example, let us take $u$ to be on a 2-simplex with 3 vertices $(0-1-2)$, then we denote the data $u$ assign on this 2-simplex as:
$$
u_{(0-1-2)}.
$$

### Question

Then How do we write $\mathfrak{P}_3(u)=\beta_{(3^{2},3)}(u\cup u)=\beta_{(9,3)}(u\cup u)$ on
a 5-simplex with 6 vertices $(0-1-2-3-4-5)$. Say, we start with the cup product $u\cup u$ that can be defined on a 4-simplex with 5 vertices $(0-1-2-3-4)$, thus
$$
(u\cup u)_{(0-1-2-3-4)} = u_{(0-1-2)} u_{(2-3-4)}.
$$
which is a product of two 2-cocycles on the 2-simplex with 3 vertices $(0-1-2)$ and another 2-simplex with 3 vertices $(2-3-4)$. How do we write explicitly on the 5-simplex $(0-1-2-3-4-5)$:
$$
\mathfrak{P}_3(u)_{(0-1-2-3-4-5)}=\beta_{(9,3)}(u_{(i-j-k)} u_{(k-l-m)})=?
$$
So we have $\mathfrak{P}_3: H^2(-,\Z_{3})\to H^5(-,\Z_{9})$ on the 5-simplex?

Comment: Could you explain why you view this operation as a Postnikov square? Note that the same operation defined on an odd dimensional cohomology group would be zero, since cup squares are $2$-torsion by graded commutatitvity and your coefficents are $3$-primary.

Comment: You may well have already looked at this reference, but section 5 of Whitehead's paper, On the Theory of Obstructions, Annals 54, No. 1 (1951), pp. 68-84 has a simplicial formula for the Postnikov square.